# Design of reputation engine

Tags: data-structures, graph, nosql, domain-driven-design

Lets imagine a social network where each user can gain reputation from others by, say, delegation. So given A and B initially have a reputation of 1 when A delegates to B then A has 0 and B has 2.
Then B can delegate to C and so on.

Also - the delagation has its scope, and scopes can be nested. So A can delegate the reputaion on all topics, or only programming, or only c#. And he can delegate on programming to B but on C# to C. That means the final reputation varies depending on a given scope.

So we get a kind of directed graph structure (probably a tree but it's not yet clear what about cycles) which we need to traverse to calculate the reputation.

I'm trying to model that with DDD principles and I'm not sure what is the aggregate here.

I suppose the delegation tree/graph is a candidate for that as the aggregate is a unit of consistency. However that means the aggregates would be very large. The scope thing complicates it even more because it makes an aggregate boundry not clear. Is delegation on C# a part of aggregate with delegations on programming?

What about user? As an aggregate it would have to store references (delegations) to/from other users. Again - which aggregate a given user belongs to?

A separate question is how to efficiently calculate the reputation. I guess the graph database will be more apropriate than relational in this case but is that the only good answer?

Comment: Why not use a graph db and focus less on the tactical DDD patterns?

Comment: @YvesReynhout -- are you suggesting that people jump straight into an implementation without doing any design first? This does sound astonishingly stupid.

Comment: If you read that into my remark, you're misinterpreting my words. Less focus on the OO friendly tactical patterns and embracing the graph paradigm might prove to be a useful exploration. Design is not analysis, design exploration is not analysis either.

Answer (score 1):

A root aggregate in is meant to enforce invariants. The rules of delegation you've informed us about are one set of invariants. Not knowing what other invariants you may require it is hard to tell what a suitable root aggregate would be, but simply going by what you've presented "user" seems to me a perfect root aggregate to enforce all your delegation rules as invariants. A user may have one or more delegation scopes, which themselves may be root aggregates. A user can, under the rules of delegation, delegate to another user, which may in turn delegate under those same rules. This allows you to enforce all your invariants and there is no problem storing references to (other) users under the rules of DDD.

Keep asking how you can enforce your domain specific rules consistently and you will find your root aggregates.

On your separate question: a graph db seems like a better idea then a relation database, but it's hard to tell with limited information. I suggest that you post this question separately and include your considerations about relational versus graph databases.